# How can I separate the files in col4?

Tags: php

How can I separate the displayed files in col4? The problem is that all of the files are getting displayed in all the column.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$query="SELECT * from test2";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[$row['id']] = array("col1" => $row['id'],"col2" => $row['name'],  
 "col3" => $row['email'],"col4" => $row['file']);
 }
$file=$_FILES['file'];
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "Uploads/".$file['name']);
?>

<form action="#" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
<table align="" border="1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <th>col4</th> 
        <th>col3</th> 
        <th>col2</th> 
        <th>col1</th>
    </tr>
     <?php
   foreach ($data as $i) { ?>
    /* here is the problem, all the files are displayed together */
        <td><?php
        $files=scandir("Uploads");
        for ($a=2; $a < count($files) ; $a++) { 
        ?>
        <a download="<?php echo $files[$a]?>" href="Uploads/<?php echo 
     $files[$a]?>"><?php echo $files[$a] ?>;</a>
        <?php
        }?></td>
       /* until here */
        <td> <?php echo $i['col3']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $i['col2']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $i['col1']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It seems like you get all the files with `scandir` and then loop through them on each of your data array entries. So it makes sense that it's including all of them each time. I'm not exactly sure what your endgoal is though. Do you want to only show certain files? Or show them all in the column but separated by a blank line? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `<br/>` after the `</a>`

```
<a download="<?php echo $files[$a]?>" href="Uploads/<?php echo 
 $files[$a]?>"><?php echo $files[$a] ?>;</a><br/>
```